# lightning fields distorted with winter 18

Tags: lightning, lightning-design-system, winter18

i am not sure if any has faced this problem but looks like our lightning fields have been distorted with winter 18 release , i have tried manual sizing , and below lds 2.2.2 but nothing seems to get the sizing and spacing in proper format.any thoughts ? [image]

```
        <!--<ltng:require styles="/resource/SLDS222/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-ltng.css,
                      /resource/SLDS222/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-ltng.min.css,
                      resource/SLDS222/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-vf.css,
                      resource/SLDS222/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-vf.min.css" />-->
```

Comment: The base styling native to the platform (internally) has changed with W18 (see release notes). I don't believe the stylesheets themselves were to change, just the way Salesforce was handling them internally. If you have copies of the latest style sheets, I would recommend you file a case with Salesforce & also check display drivers if all your users have the same/similar machines.

Comment: please share your component code